# Which public properties does SelectList class present under System.Web.Mvc namespace exposes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

One of the parameterized constructor of SelectList class looks like this:-

```
public SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, object selectedValue);
```

My problem is I want to assign some values to dataValueField and dataTextField but not while instantiating the class rather at a later stage may be after going for some checks and then dynamically decide what values to pass to.

The problem that I am facing is there is only one way to pass values of dataValueField and dataTextField and that is via the parameterized constructor.

Is there a way I can use some of the properties of the class to assign the values of dataValueField and dataTextField.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dataValueField` and `dataTextField` are private members of `MultiSelectList`, which is the base class for `SelectList` and so you can set these fields using reflection. For example:

```
  var selectList = new SelectList(new Dictionary<int, int> { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4} });

  var privateFields = selectList.GetType().BaseType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

  privateFields.Single(i => i.Name.Contains("DataTextField"))
               .SetValue(selectList, "value");

  privateFields.Single(i => i.Name.Contains("DataValueField"))
               .SetValue(selectList, "key");
```